# Does pytest have anything like google test's non-fatal EXPECT_* behavior?

Tags: python, pytest, googletest

I'm more familiar with the google test framework and know about the primary behavior pair they support about `ASSERT_*` vs `EXPECT_*` which are the fatal and non-fatal assert modes.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md#assertions):

> The assertions come in pairs that test the same thing but have
>   different effects on the current function. `ASSERT_*` versions generate
>   fatal failures when they fail, and abort the current function.
>   `EXPECT_*` versions generate nonfatal failures, which don't abort the
>   current function. Usually EXPECT_* are preferred, as they allow more
>   than one failures to be reported in a test. However, you should use
>   ASSERT_* if it doesn't make sense to continue when the assertion in
>   question fails.

**Question**: does pytest also have a non fatal assert flavor or mode I can enable?

It's nice to allow a full range of tests to maximally execute to get the richest failure history rather than abort at the first failure and potentially hide subsequent failures that have to be discovered piecewise by running multiple instances of the test application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no feature like that in `pytest`. Plain `assert` statements will fail the test immediately when the result of an expression is falsey. For a non-fatal assertion, you could use a function call - the [answer from hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50632206/674039) mentions a 3rd-party pytest plugin providing such a function. You could easily recreate the EXPECT_* idea without using a plugin by appending to a list of errors and then asserting the list is empty at the end of the test.

> It's nice to allow a full range of tests to maximally execute to get the richest failure history rather than abort at the first failure and potentially hide subsequent failures that have to be discovered piecewise by running multiple instances of the test application.

Opinions differ on whether this is nice or not.  In Python OSS, the popular approach is: write more tests, write smaller tests, and write tests that (ideally) only assert on one thing. Every potential "subsequent failure that is discovered piecewise" would be written in its own separate test.

Answer (score 5):

I use [`pytest-assume`](https://github.com/astraw38/pytest-assume) for non-fatal assertions. It does the job pretty well.

#### Installation

As usual,

```
$ pip install pytest-assume
```

#### Usage example

```python
import pytest


def test_spam():
    pytest.assume(True)
    pytest.assume(False)

    a, b = True, False
    pytest.assume(a == b)

    pytest.assume(1 == 0)
    pytest.assume(1 < 0)

    pytest.assume('')
    pytest.assume([])
    pytest.assume({})
```

If you feel writing `pytest.assume` is a bit too much, just alias the import:

```python
import pytest.assume as expect


def test_spam():
    expect(True)
    ...
```

Running the above test yields:

```
$ pytest -v
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-3.6.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /data/gentoo64-prefix/u0_a82/projects/stackoverflow/so-50630845
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /data/gentoo64-prefix/u0_a82/projects/stackoverflow/so-50630845, inifile:
plugins: assume-1.2
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_spam.py::test_spam FAILED                                            [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
__________________________________ test_spam ___________________________________
test_spam.py:6: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume(False)


test_spam.py:9: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume(a == b)


test_spam.py:11: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume(1 == 0)


test_spam.py:12: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume(1 < 0)


test_spam.py:13: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume('')


test_spam.py:14: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume([])


test_spam.py:14: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume([])


test_spam.py:15: AssumptionFailure
        pytest.assume({})

------------------------------------------------------------
Failed Assumptions: 7
=========================== 1 failed in 0.18 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: I've seen `import pytest.assume` and `from pytest import assume` but neither of those work for me. I simply did `pip install pytest-assume`. Why isn't the package to import called `pytest_assume`, therefore `from pytest_assume import assume` or something similar? This doesn't work either. Why is this different from every other pip package? Is there pytest plugin support in pip? If so, how do I refresh the `pytest` module's view of the world?

Comment: @davidA 1. the import will only work when you are actually running tests with `pytest`. It's not a real import, rather a module monkeypatching for tests only. 2. If you have installed `pytest-assume`, copied the example test snippet from my answer and the import fails when you run `pytest`, most likely it's an issue with your local setup. Often, the cause is having multiple Python installations and using `pip install` for the wrong interpreter version.

Comment: @davidA To test that, run `python -c "import pytest_assume"`. If it fails, run `pip -V` and `python -V` and compare the interpreter versions listed - most probably you've installed the package for the wrong interpreter. If it works, you have another, a more severe issue - best is to ask a separate question for that, providing more details about your local setup.

Comment: ah, that explains it - thank you. I see the plugin detected and listed by pytest when it runs, so it is installed correctly.