# How to use multiple failures in Unittest and print them as a fail without ending the test?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, allure

I need to write a test with a several procedures that check a several use cases (steps).
For every Step it may be a Sub-step.
Every Step/Sub-step is checking something else, for example:

```
Procedure 1 :
 Step 1 : Verify something
 Step 2 : Compare ....
  Sub-step 2.1 : Compare ...
  Sub-step 2.2 : Compare ...
 Step 3 : Configure ....
```

Every Step or Sub-step can fail/pass and the test will continue normally.

```
Step 1 : Verify something     - PASS
Step 2 : Compare ....         - FAIL
 Sub-step 2.1 : Compare ...  - PASS
 Sub-step 2.2 : Compare ...  - FAIL
Step 3 : Configure ....       - PASS
```

Also i need the results to be in interactive HTML result file (i used Allure)
step by step with the result and information for each step.

I tried to use Pytest and Allure (for the interactive HTML result report file) but to represent a fail i need to use Assert, and Assert exception cause the test to fail immediately.

Is there any other framework besides Allure that can help me to create HTML report file in a high level and represent a failure in other way than Assert?
Is there any way to make Allure to show a fail without using Assert?

```py
   def test_procedure_1(self):
        with allure.step("1. Configure "):
           Assert 0
        with allure.step("2. prints"):
           Assert 1
        with allure.step("3. attached"):
           Assert 0
        with allure.step("4. compare"):
           Assert 1
```

Other example :

```py
    def test_procedure_2(self):
        with self.subTest("step 1:"):
            Assert 0
            with self.subTest("step 1.1:"):
                Assert 1
                with self.subTest("step 1.1.1:"):
                    Assert 1
                    with self.subTest("step 1.1.1.1:"):
                        Assert 0
        with self.subTest("step 2:"):
             Assert 1
```

Comment: Do you mean `assert` when writing `Assert`? All python keywords are lowercase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does pytest have anything like google test's non-fatal EXPECT\_\* behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630845/does-pytest-have-anything-like-google-tests-non-fatal-expect-behavior)